# why default layout information still appeared after deleted the default Layout in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I just created new project in ASP.NET MVC and created new layout and deleted the default layout
but when I run the project its show the new layout and down it shows the default layout information's
ASP.NET and its information please see the image .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2CQe.png)

why its show the default layout text I deleted already
and how to remove it

This is the new layout footer code :

```
<!-- Footer Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light footer pt-5 mt-5 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
        <div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row g-5">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="text-white mb-3">Quick Link</h4>
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="">About Us</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="">Contact Us</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="">Privacy Policy</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="">Terms & Condition</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="">FAQs & Help</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="text-white mb-3">Contact</h4>
                    <p class="mb-2"><i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt me-3"></i>123 Street, New York, USA</p>
                    <p class="mb-2"><i class="fa fa-phone-alt me-3"></i>+012 345 67890</p>
                    <p class="mb-2"><i class="fa fa-envelope me-3"></i>info@example.com</p>
                    <div class="d-flex pt-2">
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social" href=""><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-social" href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="text-white mb-3">Gallery</h4>
                    <div class="row g-2 pt-2">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-1.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-2.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-3.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-2.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-3.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <img class="img-fluid bg-light p-1" src=@Url.Content("/Contents/img/course-1.jpg") alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <h4 class="text-white mb-3">Newsletter</h4>
                    <p>Dolor amet sit justo amet elitr clita ipsum elitr est.</p>
                    <div class="position-relative mx-auto" style="max-width: 400px;">
                        <input class="form-control border-0 w-100 py-3 ps-4 pe-5" type="text" placeholder="Your email">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary py-2 position-absolute top-0 end-0 mt-2 me-2">SignUp</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="copyright">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-start mb-3 mb-md-0">
                        &copy; <a class="border-bottom" href="#"></a>, All Right Reserved.

                        <!--/*** This template is free as long as you keep the footer author’s credit link/attribution link/backlink. If you'd like to use the template without the footer author’s credit link/attribution link/backlink, you can purchase the Credit Removal License from "https://htmlcodex.com/credit-removal". Thank you for your support. ***/-->
                        Designed By <a class="border-bottom" href="https://htmlcodex.com">HTML Codex</a><br><br>
                        Distributed By <a class="border-bottom" href="https://themewagon.com">ThemeWagon</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-md-end">
                        <div class="footer-menu">
                            <a href="">Home</a>
                            <a href="">Cookies</a>
                            <a href="">Help</a>
                            <a href="">FQAs</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer End -->
    <!-- Back to Top -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-lg-square back-to-top"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></a>


    <!-- JavaScript Libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/lib/wow/wow.min.js")></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/lib/easing/easing.min.js")></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/lib/waypoints/waypoints.min.js")></script>
    <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/lib/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js")></script>

    <!-- Template Javascript -->
    <script src=@Url.Content("/Contents/js/main.js")></script>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

I searched also the files I didnt found the text appeared in the project from the default layout from where its appear can you check the image please ?

Comment: Go to Views > Home > Index.cshtml then Remove code.

Comment: @Amit thank you so much that's it how I didn't find it :)                                                          
            add the answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Views > Home > Index.cshtml then Remove code.